# How to insert data into marklogic database in already existing file using curl RESTAPI

Tags: curl, marklogic, rest

I searched over the internet and found nothing about this making me rethink that "may be we can't insert data into already existing file in Marklogic".But, I want to verify here
I know using curl PUT command we can update or create a new document
I have created a json using following query

```
**curl -v -X PUT \
  --digest --user rest-writer:x \
  -d'{"recipe": {"name" :"Apple pie", "fromScratch":true, "ingredients":"The Universe"}}' \
  'http://localhost:8011/LATEST/documents?uri=/example/recipe.json'**
```

After creating this, i wanted to add another recipe such as below in the same file /example/recipe.json

```
"name" :"Chocolate Cake", "fromScratch":yes, "ingredients":"Coca"
```

How can i achieve this using curl in Marklogic?

Comment: Are you trying to append the content to update the document? Or do you want to store a separate document? If the latter, ensure that you give it a different and distinct URI (i.e. `documents?uri=/example/recipe/chocolate-cake.json`)

Comment: I would recommend not storing all recipes in one file. You'll have many benefits from it. For starters, searching individual recipes will be much more straight-forward that way. And data updates would scale much better too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly insert other JSON objects in an existing JSON document. Being a multi-model database, data model should be the first consideration.

> In order to facilitate JSON object update, the JSON model should be:

```
{
  "recipe" : {
    "recipe1":{
      "name" : "Apple pie", 
      "fromScratch" : true, 
      "ingredients" : "The Universe"
    }
  }
}
```

> Then construct an update JSON content (choose one of below options) called `add-recipe.json`:

1. Add JSON object after `recipe1`

```
{ 
  "patch": [
   { "insert": {
       "context": "/recipe/recipe1",
         "position": "after",
           "content":   
            { "recipe2": {
                "name" : "Chocolate Cake", 
                "fromScratch" : true, 
                "ingredients" : "Coca"
            }}
    
    }}
] }
```

2. Add JSON object before `recipe1`:

```
{ 
  "patch": [
   { "insert": {
       "context": "/recipe/recipe1",
         "position": "before",
           "content":   
            { "recipe2": {
                "name" : "Chocolate Cake", 
                "fromScratch" : true, 
                "ingredients" : "Coca"
            }}
    
    }}
] }
```

3. Add JSON object following the last child (if you have nested JSON objects):

```
{ 
  "patch": [
   { "insert": {
       "context": "/recipe",
         "position": "last-child",
           "content":   
            { "recipe2": {
                "name" : "Chocolate Cake", 
                "fromScratch" : true, 
                "ingredients" : "Coca"
            }}
    
    }}
] }
```

> Finally, perform a `patch` REST API request to complete the operation:

```
curl --anyauth --user {username}:{password} -X PATCH -d @./add-recipe.json -i -H "Content-type: application/json" "http://{hostname}:{port-number}/v1/documents?uri=/example/recipe.json"
```